# How to extract positions of a set of linear independent components of a matrix / tensor?

Tags: matrix

Given a in general non-symmetric matrix / tensor of arbitrary shape `A`, I want to obtain efficiently the positions of a set of linear independent components of `A`. My approach until now is slowly start with the first component and adding linear independent components after checking linear independency (with `ForAll` components `comp`, `Exists` some linear combinations with coefficients `c` and `Resolve` for a boolean statement).

```
LinearIndependentComponents[A_] := Module[
   {comp, li, c, cs, q},
   comp = Flatten@A;
   li = {comp[[1]]};
   Do[
    c = Array[cs, Length@li];
    q = Resolve[
      Exists[Evaluate@c, 
       ForAll[Evaluate@Variables@comp, c.li == comp[[j]]]]];
    If[Not@q, AppendTo[li, comp[[j]]]]
    , {j, 2, Length@comp}
    ];
   Do[
    li[[i]] = First@Position[A, li[[i]]];
    , {i, Length@li}
    ];
   li
   ];
```

My approach is horribly slow for large matrices and tensors. Do you know how to do this more efficiently? I dont use `Variables`, since for some expressions, see Example 2 and Example 4 down below, the list of variables of Mathematica is not the right answer.

**Example 1:** non-symmetric matrix

```
A = {{a, b, 4 b - a}, {c, a - 5 b, a}, {d, b + c + a, b}};
MatrixForm@A
LinearIndependentComponents@A
```

[image]

**Example 2:** symmetrized matrix

```
A = Array[a, {3, 3}];
B = A + Transpose@A;
Length@LinearIndependentComponents@B
Length@Variables@B
```

> 6
>
> 9

**Example 3:** partly symmetrized fourth-order tensor

```
A = Normal@
   SymmetrizedArray[
    pos_ :> Subscript[a, pos], {3, 3, 3, 3}, {Symmetric[{1, 2}], 
     Symmetric[{3, 4}]}];
Length@Variables@A
Length@LinearIndependentComponents@A
```

> 36
>
> 36

**Example 4**: slightly twisted expression

```
A=Array[a, {3,3}];
A=2*(A+Transpose@A);
A=A+Reverse@A;
LinearIndependentComponents@A
```

> {{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,2}}